# executing binary from code fails but running it from command line works

Tags: go, kubernetes, kubectl

I am trying to upgrade a little [netperf-tester](https://github.com/kubernetes/contrib/tree/master/netperf-tester) from `contrib` respository but I have one problem as I am not a good developer
I have added one more arg for `kubectl`:

```
args := []string{"run", serviceName, "--image=" + image, fmt.Sprintf("--port=%d", port), "--hostport=65530", fmt.Sprintf("--overrides='{ \"apiVersion\": \"extensions/v1beta1\", \"spec\": { \"nodeSelector\": { \"kubernetes.io/hostname\": \"%s\" } } }'", node)}
```

but it gives me an error:

```
2017/05/05 10:18:02 kubectl path := kubectl
2017/05/05 10:18:02 Running kubectl with args := [run netperf-tester-host --image=paultiplady/netserver:ubuntu.2 --port=12865 --hostport=65530 --overrides='{ "apiVersion": "extensions/v1beta1", "spec": { "nodeSelector": { "kubernetes.io/hostname": "10.122.16.118" } } }']
2017/05/05 10:18:04 Error adding service: exit status 1
Output: error: Invalid JSON Patch
```

when I am running it manually it works

```
$ kubectl run netperf-tester-host --image=paultiplady/netserver:ubuntu.2 --port=12865 --hostport=65530 --overrides='{ "apiVersion": "extensions/v1beta1", "spec": { "nodeSelector": { "kubernetes.io/hostname": "10.122.16.118" } } }'
deployment "netperf-tester-host" created
```

if anyone can point me where the error is I would be very grateful

Comment: the prablem was single quotes in `--overrides` arg for exec, it should look like this:

`args := []string{"run", serviceName, "--image=" + image, fmt.Sprintf("--port=%d", port), "--hostport=65530", fmt.Sprintf("--overrides={ \"apiVersion\": \"extensions/v1beta1\", \"spec\": { \"nodeSelector\": { \"kubernetes.io/hostname\": \"%s\" } } }", node)}`

Answer (score 0):

the prablem was single quotes in `--overrides` arg for `exec` according to [this thread](http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.org.google.containers/1788), it should look like this:

```
args := []string{"run", serviceName, "--image=" + image, fmt.Sprintf("--port=%d", port), "--hostport=65530", fmt.Sprintf("--overrides={ \"apiVersion\": \"extensions/v1beta1\", \"spec\": { \"nodeSelector\": { \"kubernetes.io/hostname\": \"%s\" } } }", node)}
```